# Young tableaux and braces

Tags: ytableau

I would like to use the following drawing in my memoir:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{ytableau}
    ~               & \none & \none & \none         & \none \\
    \none[\vdots]   & \none & \none & \none         & \none \\
    ~               & \none & \none & \none         & \none \\
    ~               &       & \none & \none         & \none \\
    ~               &       &       & \none[\dots]  &        
    \end{ytableau}
    \caption{Diagram of $\lambda = (2 + u, 2, 1^v)$}
    \end{figure}
```

I would like to add braces on the top three cases (to indicate that there is $u$ cases) and on the three leftmost **edit: rightmost** cases (to indicate that there is v cases). How can I do that? The usual \left{ and \right. doesn't work in \ytableau.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A sketch of the desired result would be necessary: just a photo of the result scribbled on paper would do.

Comment: I would like a drawing like in the answer below, but with the bottom brace at the right instead of at the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind tuning things you won't need additional packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{r@{}l}
    \raisebox{-2.5ex}{$u\left\{\vphantom{\begin{array}{c}~\\[6ex] ~
    \end{array}}\right.$} &
    \begin{ytableau}
    ~               & \none & \none & \none         & \none \\
    \none[\vdots]   & \none & \none & \none         & \none \\
    ~               & \none & \none & \none         & \none \\
    ~               &       & \none & \none         & \none \\
    ~               &       &       & \none[\dots]  &        
    \end{ytableau}\\[-1.5ex]
    &\hspace{3em}$\underbrace{\hspace{4.8em}}_{\displaystyle v}$
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Diagram of $\lambda = (2 + u, 2, 1^v)$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, as `ytableau` loads `pgf`, it may not be too far a stretch to use `tikzmark`, but this may make more sense if you are loading `tikz` anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}
    \begin{ytableau}
    \tikzmarknode{v1}{~}               & \none & \none & \none         & \none \\
    \none[\vdots]   & \none & \none & \none         & \none \\
    \tikzmarknode{v2}{~}               & \none & \none & \none         & \none \\
    ~               &       & \none & \none         & \none \\
    ~               &       & \tikzmarknode{u1}{~}      & \none[\dots]  &       \tikzmarknode{u2}{~}
    \\
    \end{ytableau}\\[-1ex]
    ~
\end{tabular}
    \caption{Diagram of $\lambda = (2 + u, 2, 1^v)$}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,decoration=brace]
 \draw[decorate,thick] ([xshift=-1em,yshift=-0.5em]v2.south west) -- 
 ([xshift=-1em,yshift=1em]v1.north west) node[midway,left]{$v$};
 \draw[decorate,thick] ([xshift=1em,yshift=-0.75em]u2.south west) -- 
 ([xshift=-1em,yshift=-0.75em]u1.south west) node[midway,below]{$u$};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that! But I didn't wrote the good thing, I wanted the bottom bracket to be on the right cases, and I don't understand the code you wrote enough to adapt it... (see edit) It would be grat if you could help me again...

Comment: @eti902 I made an update.

Answer (score 3):

use of the `ytableu` have some advantages, however in your particular case it is worth to consider pure `tikz` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,% must be loaded after decorations.pathreplacing
                matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
BC/.style = {decorate, % for fancy calligraphic braces
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=5pt, raise=1mm},
        very thick, pen colour={black}
            },
                    ]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
             nodes={draw, minimum size=6mm, anchor=center},
             column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
             row sep=-\pgflinewidth
             ]
{
~   &   &   &   &   \\
|[draw=none,text height=3mm]| \vdots
    &   &   &   &   \\
~   &   &   &   &   \\
~   & ~ &   &   &   \\
~   & ~ & ~ & |[draw=none]|\dots
                & ~ \\
};
\draw[BC] (m-3-1.south west) -- node[left =2.2mm] {$v$} (m-1-1.north west);
\draw[BC] (m-5-5.south east) -- node[below=2.2mm] {$u$} (m-5-3.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Diagram of $\lambda = (2 + u, 2, 1^v)$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]